# Cache color hint to transparent doesn't remove fade effect

Tags: android, listview

I am using a ListView and I want to remove the fade effect on the edge when the listview is scrolled. I have tried putting

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

to the ListView but the fade effect doesn't go away. How to remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the fading edge of a ListView:

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```